# Как правильно: "цветок роза" или "цветок розы"?

Tags: untagged

Пишутся раздельно два нарицательных существительных, соотносящихся как родовое и видовое понятия, если они являются членами научной классификации природных объектов. Ср.: *птица иволга, цветок роза, металл литий*.

Можно ли говорить "цветок розы"? Или в этом случае под розой подразумевается куст, на котором растут цветы - розы?

Как правильно писать склонять "газ кислород": "газа кислорода" или "газа кислород"?

Answer (score 2):

Как  известно, всё относительно, и нет ничего  абсолютного верного.
Поэтому все сочетания нужно рассматривать применительно  **к конкретным ситуациям**, только тогда мы можем судить об их **правильности и обоснованности.**

**Из словаря:** **РОЗА**,  1. Декоративный кустарник с крупными ароматными цветками разнообразной окраски и со стеблями, покрытыми шипами; цветки этого растения. **ЦВЕТОК**,  мн. цветы и (спец.) цветки; м. 1. Часть растения; орган размножения, обычно имеющий вид венчика из лепестков, окружающих пестик с тычинками.

Итак, **грамматически верны все варианты**:  декоративный кустарник роза, цветок роза, цветок розы (розового кустарника).  Научная классификация здесь не так важна и принципиальна. У нас есть определение слова «цветок» в общем случае, поэтому сочетание «цветок роза» вполне корректно.

А теперь посмотрим, **в каких ситуациях мы применяем эти слова и сочетания**. Вот история от поэта И.И. Дмитриева, в котором он  использует только **название цветка:** «Всех цветочков боле **розу** я любил; ею только в поле взор мой веселил. **К розе**, как нарочно, привилась полынь. **Роза** не увяла —тот же самый цвет; но не та уж стала: аромата нет!»

Очень трогательно… Собственно говоря, мы в большинстве случаев **поступаем так же**, то есть  обходимся только названием цветка. А когда же мы используем сочетания? Вот примеры из Нацкорпуса:

**1. Когда говорим о  разных растениях**

Солнцу был посвящен подорожник, хранящий жар и силу, Венере ― вербена, цветок любви и веселья... Символическое значение растений  трактовалось неодинаково в разные времена и в различных странах. Тот же **цветок розы** ― образец совершенства ― означал не только любовь, красоту, изящество, удовольствие, радость, но мог олицетворять и прямо противоположные свойства: молитву, медитацию, тайну. [Еремей Парнов. Александрийская гемма (1990)]

**2. Когда используем  сложное сочетания**

Шарик начинал набухать, потом раскрывался и превращался то в черного слона с красными глазами, то в оранжевого дракона или **цветок розы с зелеными листьями.** [К. Г. Паустовский. Книга о жизни. Далекие годы (1946)]

**3. Когда говорим о разных цветах**

Цветы всякие есть. Вот есть **цветок роза.** Так и звание у нее ― королева цветов.  ― А, да. Хорош **цветок роза**? ― Хорош. Да к чему тебе-то? [Б. Л. Горбатов. Большая вода (1939)]